# React components not appearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a repo at https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/anthony-project-react

I have the homepage showing links, and when you click the links react-router works. But the text of the component is not showing up, like  `<div>Login page</div>`, `<div>Homepage</div>`, etc.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import reducers from './reducers';

import Nav from './Nav';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignupMain from './components/SignupMain';


const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    (
      <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
          <Router history={browserHistory}>
              <Route path="/" component={Nav}>
                  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                  <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                  <Route path='/signup-main' component={SignupMain}/>
              </Route>
          </Router>
      </Provider>
  ), document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Nav.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header navbar-brand">
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" className="navbar-right">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/login" onlyActiveOnIndex>Login</Link></li>
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/signup-main" onlyActiveOnIndex>Signup</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


// export Nav as default;
```

components/Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Homepage</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why aren't these components showing up on the page?

Comment: what is your react router version? Your code is not accessible. Put it into some public repo like github and share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your other routes are nested inside the route for 'Nav' component, it should render its children somewhere. For that, you have to put `this.props.children` where you want to render nested components in JSX of Nav component.

```
export default class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header navbar-brand">
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" className="navbar-right">
                        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/login" onlyActiveOnIndex>Login</Link></li>
                            <li><Link activeClassName="active" to="/signup-main" onlyActiveOnIndex>Signup</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
               <div>{this.props.children}</div> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: correct, I do see that clause now in the bottom of our `Nav` component at work, but didn't know what it meant. Thanks tharaka